# Transport related data set - Milano or Trentino

Tags: data-request

Does anyone have an idea where traffic data set/s (traffic volumes, OD-Matrix, models?) can be downloaded for Milano or Trentino regions in Italy, for 2013.?

I tried on http://dati.trentino.it/ and http://dati.comune.milano.it/, but either this data does not exist, or is not available in adequate time frame...

BR
Toni